# coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^5+x^7)^{20}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

I found this questions from past year maths competition in my country, I've tried any possible way to find it, but it is just way too hard.

> find the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of $(1+x^5+x^7)^{20}$
>
> (A)3400 (B)3410 (C)3420 (D)3430 (E)3440

so it would be $$x^{140} + ...... + 1$$

This requires binomial theorem and Multinomial theorem, but I'm not sure how to calculate it. Any tips or formula would be appreciate.

Comment: **Hint:** The only way to produce $17$ as a sum of 5's and 7's is as $5+5+17$. So you need to assign two $x^5$s and one $x^7$ among the 20 factors.

Comment: "I found this questions from past year maths competition in my country, I've tried any possible way to find it, but it is just way too hard." You **really** may not include this preamble in any question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usage of the multinomial coefficient $(k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_n)$!:

> $$
> \big( 1 + x^5 + x^7\big)^{20} = \sum_{k_1=1}^{20} \sum_{k_2=1}^{20-k_1}
> (k_1, k_2, 20 - k_1 - k_2)! x^{5k_1} x^{7k_2},
> $$

where

> $$
> (k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_n)! = \frac{ (k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_n )! }
> { k_1! k_2! \cdots k_n!}.
> $$

So we get $k_1=2$ and $k_2=1$, thus

> $$
> (2,1,17)! = \frac{(2+1+17)!}{
> \begin{array}
> {ccc}2! & 1! & 17!\\
> \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow\\
> 2 \times 5 & 1 \times 7 & 17 \times 0
> \end{array}
> } = 3420.
> $$

[change in order due to comment of @Henning Makholm]

Comment: For consistency with your first formula you should be speaking abouth $(2,1,17)!$ rather than $(17,2,1)!$.

Comment: That would be nicer indeed. But there is symmetry in the coefficients... I changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

$17$ can only be obtained by using two $5$s and one $7$ . These two $5$s can be obtained in $\binom{20}2$ ways which is $190$ and the $7$ can be got in from one of the remaining 18 brackets. So $190$ x $18$ = $3420$ is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

$(1+x^5+x^7)^{20}=\{(1+x^5)+x^7\}^{20}$

$=(1+x^5)^{20}+\binom{20}1(1+x^5)^{20-1}(x^7)^1+\binom{20}2(1+x^5)^{20-2}(x^7)^2+\cdots+(x^7)^{20}$

So the required sum will be

the coefficient of $x^{17}$ in $(1+x^5)^{20}$

$+\binom{20}1\cdot$ the coefficient of $x^{17-7}$ in $(1+x^5)^{20-1}$

$+\binom{20}2\cdot$ the coefficient of $x^{17-7\cdot2}$ in $(1+x^5)^{20-2}$

Clearly the exponent of $x$ in $(1+x^5)^n$ will be divisible by $5$

So, the first &  the last summand must be zero

Now for the coefficient of $x^{17-7\cdot1}$ in $(1+x^5)^{20-1},$

the $r+1$th term $\binom{19}r(x^5)^r=\binom{19}rx^{5r}$ and we need $5r=10\iff r=?$

Answer (score 4):

So if you think about

$$ (1 + x^5 + x^7)^{20} $$

That intuitively is just

$$ ((1 + x^5) + x^7) \times ((1 + x^5) + x^7) \times ((1 + x^5) + x^7) ... $$

Which can be expanded out term by term. By the Binomial Theorem as

$$ (1 + x^5)^{20} (x^7)^0 + \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}(1 + x^5)^{19}x^7 + \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}(1 + x^5)^{18}x^{14} ...$$

Now we can take each of the $$(1 + x^5)$$ terms and expand them as well.

Note that the number 17 can be expressed as sum in terms of multiples of 5 and 7 as

$$ 10 + 7$$

If we consider say $15$ in the sum it's too big, and same for $14$ likewise arguments can be made to show that $5$ by itself won't add to a positive multiple of 7 to make 17.

So that means every power of 17 is contained in the term

$$\begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}(1 + x^5)^{19}x^7 $$

Of our binomial expression. We need to find the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in

$$ (1 + x^5)^{19} $$

Call that C. Then

$$ C \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Is the answer.

By Binomial Theorem:

$$  (1 + x^5)^{19}  = 1 + \begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}x^5 + \begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}x^{10} ... $$

So then $C = \begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} $

So the answer then is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} $$

To get more advanced techniques (it is worthwhile to take a look at the multinomial theorems). They generalize these ideas for arbitrarily large sums raised to integer powers like the binomial theorem for 2 elements raised to a power.

Note that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}  = \frac{19!}{2!17!} 20 = 19 \times 9 \times 20 = 3420$$